# Insert password via expect to the ssh connection

Tags: ssh, passwords, expect

I've fighting for quite while, but I'm not able to force make it work ...
Script is running on the HPUX 11.31 server ...
Tried google and test many option, but none is working ... any idea?
It seems like password is inserted, but not executed ["enter not pressed"]
Thank you very much for advise.

Home: cat MyScript.exp

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -d

set prompt {[#$] }
lassign $argv username server password

spawn /usr/bin/ssh $server -l $username ls -la /folder | /usr/bin/grep -c -i "MyFile"
expect {
 "*password:*" { send "$password\r" }
}
```

---- debug run ----

```
Home: ./MyScript.exp MyUserName MyServer MyPassword

expect version 5.45
argv[0] = /usr/local/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = ./MyScript.exp  argv[3] = MyUserName  argv[4] = MyServer  argv[5] = MyPassword
set argc 3
set argv0 "./MyScript.exp"
set argv "MyUserName MyServer MyPassword"
executing commands from command file ./MyScript.exp
spawn /usr/bin/ssh MyServer -l MyUserName ls -la /folder | /usr/bin/grep -c -i MyFile
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {18256}
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*password:*"? no
MyUserName@MyServer's password:
expect: does "MyUserName@MyServer's password: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*password:*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "MyUserName@MyServer's password: "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "MyUserName@MyServer's password: "
send: sending "MyPassword\r" to { exp4 }
```

Comment: Your debug output doesn't really show a problem, your ssh-ls-grep command might just not produce any output. You say you're getting "enter not pressed" somewhere? That's not in your debug output. Where are you seeing that?

Comment: You seems to be right. Also, I have found out, the command on the ssh connection does not support grep. So, I will have to save whole output to the file and then do the grep what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0):

If that's your entire script, then after you send the password,  the script ends, taking the ssh connection with it. Make your last line

```
expect eof
```

That will wait for the ssh connection to end gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "expect eof" case...
I call the script from other script like this>

```
$PATH/iLO_checkEXP.exp $FQDNSERVER $USER $PASSWORD > /tmp/$SERVER-SHOWALL.LOG
```

The output of the ssh connection should be saved to the /tmp/$SERVER-SHOWALL.LOG file, so I would be able to grep for text I'm looking for.

Content of the iLO_checkEXP.exp script is>

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect

set timeout 120
set hostname [lindex $argv 0]
set username [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
spawn /usr/bin/ssh -l $username -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss $hostname
expect "*: "
send "$password\r"
send "CommandWhichProvideOutput\r"
send "exit\r"
interact
```